# Work on the same git directory simultaneously

Tags: git, git-worktree

Is it possible to do the following things on the same git directory simultaneously:

- compiling on one branch
- working on another branch

Comment: What about just trying?

Comment: @dan1st It can work normally without modifying files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **additional worktrees** for this. One worktree can be checked out on a branch, with its own directory, where you do your compiling.

And the other worktree can be checked out on another branch, in a distinct directory, for you to keep on working without interfering with the compiling going on in the other one.

Check the doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_description).

Typically :

```
git worktree add <path/to/new/worktree>
```

then `cd` between your directories to execute commands on either worktree.

Comment: For another newbie problem - when I execute `git worktree -h`, the output seems not full related to the link in your answer:
```
❯ git worktree -h
usage: git worktree add [<options>] <path> [<branch>]
   or: git worktree prune [<options>]
   or: git worktree list [<options>]
```
There is no `git worktree remove`.

Comment: @FangzhenSong That's odd, the output I have is complete with `git worktree remove`. What's your `git --version`?

Comment: Oh, it was indeed with the git version. 
After upgrading, this works normally.